# Get common elements after $group mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have some transactions data as follows :

```
[{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5d319aa8df4026532fe5036f"),
  "transaction" : ISODate("2018-10-16T04:00:07.000Z"),
  "cardnumber" : "1000 0000 0002 0356"
},{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d319aa8df4026532fe5035x"),
  "transaction" : ISODate("2018-10-16T04:00:07.000Z"),
  "cardnumber" : "1000 0000 0002 0358"
},{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d319aa8df4026532fe5036d"),
  "transaction" : ISODate("2018-09-16T04:00:07.000Z"),
  "cardnumber" : "1000 0000 0002 0356"
}]
```

I have to get all the card numbers that have been use at least once every month.

So my first idea was to group them by month and year :

```
return transactionsModel.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            year: {
                $year: "$transaction"
            },
            month: {
                $month: "$transaction"
            }
        },
        results: {
            $push: '$$CURRENT.cardnumber'
        }
    },

}]).allowDiskUse(true);
```

The answer of that query is like this :

```
[
{
    "_id": {
        "year": 2018,
        "month": 9
    },
    "results": [
        "1000 0000 0002 0356"
    ]
},
{
    "_id": {
        "year": 2018,
        "month": 10
    },
    "results": [
        "1000 0000 0002 0356",
        "1000 0000 0002 0358"
    ]
}
]
```

But I don't know after that how to find the card number that are common in every groups.

expect response :

```
"results": [
        "1000 0000 0002 0356"
 ]
```

Thank in advance for your answers. If you need any other information, ask it I will try to provide what i can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "year": { "$year": "$transaction" },
      "month": { "$month": "$transaction" }
    },
    "results": { "$push": "$$CURRENT.cardnumber" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "result": { "$first": "$results" },
    "results": { "$push": "$results" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "results": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$results",
        "initialValue": "$result",
        "in": { "$setIntersection": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**Output**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/syS5kqWdiZt)

```
[
  {
    "_id": null,
    "results": [
      "1000 0000 0002 0356"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following implementation will get all the card numbers that have been use at least once every month.

```
let elements = [{
        "_id": {
            "year": 2018,
            "month": 9
        },
        "results": [
            "1000 0000 0002 0356"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "year": 2018,
            "month": 10
        },
        "results": [
            "1000 0000 0002 0356",
            "1000 0000 0002 0358"
        ]
    }
];

let result = {
    "results": []
}

let found = [];

function findUsedCardNumbers() {
    elements.forEach(element => {
        let card_numbers = element["results"];
        for (let i = 0; i < card_numbers.length; i++) {
            if (isCardNumberContains(card_numbers[i]) && !found.includes(card_numbers[i])) {
                found.push(card_numbers[i])
            }
        }
    });
    result["results"] = found;
}

function isCardNumberContains(card_number) {
    let flag = true
    try {
        elements.forEach(element => {
            flag = (element["results"].includes(card_number)) ? true : false;
            if (!flag) {
                throw BreakException;
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {

    }
    return flag;
}

findUsedCardNumbers();
console.log(result);
```

Expected result will be :

```
"results": [
     "1000 0000 0002 0356"
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can intersect results to get your expected result

```
var result = [
  {
      "_id": {
          "year": 2018,
          "month": 9
      },
      "results": [
          "1000 0000 0002 0356"
      ]
  },
  {
      "_id": {
          "year": 2018,
          "month": 10
      },
      "results": [
          "1000 0000 0002 0356",
          "1000 0000 0002 0358"
      ]
  }
  ]
const resultData = result.map(r => r.results)
function intersection(a) {
    if (a.length > 2)
        return intersection([intersection(a.slice(0, a.length / 2)), intersection(a.slice(a.length / 2))]);

    if (a.length == 1)
        return a[0];

    return a[0].filter(function(item) {
        return a[1].indexOf(item) !== -1;
    });
}
console.log(intersection(resultData))
```